# "Rezept" vs. "Rezeptur"

Tags: word-choice, noun, word-usage

Grundsätzlich geben beide Begriffe eine Anleitung zur Herstellung bzw. die zu verwendenden Inhaltsstoffe an:

- Vom Arzt bekommt man ein Rezept.
- In einer Kochshow wird ein neues Rezept vorgestellt.
- mit verbesserter Rezeptur

Wo genau besteht aber nun der Unterschied und welches Wort sollte in welchem Kontext verwendet werden?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wahrig:

> **Rezeptur**:
>
> 1. Herstellung einer
>      Arznei nach einem Rezept
> 2. der dafür bestimmte Raum in der Apotheke
>
> **Rezept**:
>
> 1. Vorschrift zum
>      Zubereiten einer Speise
> 2. schriftl. Anweisung des Arztes zur
>      Abgabe eines Medikamentes
> 3. (fig.;
>      umg.) Mittel

Die **Rezeptur** scheint also den **Prozess** des Herstellens zu beschreiben (oder einen Ort, scheint aber selten zu sein), das **Rezept** die **Anleitung** selbst oder eben "das Rezept das man vom Arzt bekommt".

Wikipedias Rezeptur Artikel sagt: "Eine Rezeptur ist ein Arzneimittel" - es wundert mich jedoch, dass Wahrig das dann nicht erwähnen würde. Auch unter "Arznei", "Medikament" oder "Medizin" wird nie auf "Rezeptur" verwiesen. Ich selbst habe das Wort vorhin noch nie in diesem Zusammenhang gehört, da traue ich Wikipedia jetzt überhaupt nicht.

Comment: +1 für ein gesundes Misstrauen gegenüber Wikis

Answer (score 8):

Das **Rezept** bezeichnet eine Anleitung zur Zubereitung einer Speise oder die Verschreibung eines Medikamentes durch einen Arzt.

Der Begriff **Rezeptur** wird immer dann verwendet, wenn es um die Herstellung eines (individuellen) Arzneimittels gemäß dem Rezept eines Arztes in einer Apotheke geht. Außerdem wird die Zusammensetzung von (industriell hergestellten) Nahrungsmitteln oder Kosmetikprodukten als Rezeptur bezeichnet.

Zwei Beispielsätze zur Verdeutlichung:

- Der Apotheker stellt eine Rezeptur *(Arzneimittel)* in der Rezeptur *(Raum)* nach dem Rezept *(Zettel mit Anweisungen)* des Arztes her.
- BackFertig, ein Hersteller von Fertigbackmischungen, hat heute seine neue Backmischung für Käsekuchen vorgestellt. Die verbesserte Rezeptur wurde nach einem Rezept der Großmutter des Firmengründers, Dr. Karl Bäcker, entwickelt.

Comment: +1 für industriell hergestellte Nahrungsmittel - ich habe familienbande in die Bio-Lebensmittelbranche, und "Rezeptur" ist dort definitiv alltagsgebräuchlich, wenn es um die Komposition von Produktionsanleitungen geht.

Answer (score 3):

Ergänzend zu puzzle möchte ich erwähnen.

Generell geht es bei Rezepten einerseits um die zu verarbeitenden Materialien und andererseits um das Verarbeitungsverfahren.

Die Bezeichnung *Rezept* im Zusammenhang mit ärztlichen [Arzneimittelverordnungen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rezept_%28Medizin%29) ist zwar umgangssprachlich gebräuchlich, aber nicht ganz zutreffend.

> Ich gehe mir vom Arzt ein Rezept holen.
>
> Ich lasse mir vom Arzt ein Rezept verschreiben.

In den meisten Fällen wird der Arzt ein Fertigarzneimittel verordnen.
Lediglich in Ausnahmefällen wird in der Apotheke auf Grund eines Rezeptes das Medikament speziell hergestellt. Nur in letzterem Fall ist es im engeren Sinne tatsächlich ein Rezept.

Comment: Die neue Rechtschreibung erlaubt zwar, _auf Grund_ in zwei Wörtern zu schreiben, aber ich kann nie umhin, mir bildlich vorzustellen, was denn nun auf dem Grund (d.h. ganz unten) passiert.